# May someone be able to fix this function please?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Like, what is the problem with it?

```
=IF(F2>6,=A18*0.5,=A18*0.6)
```

It keeps on making it just say =A18*0.5, not the actual contents of half of A18.
So can someone try make this work?

All help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

`=IF(F2>6,A18*0.5,A18*0.6)`

Source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx

Comment: Heh heh, I can't belive that worked. Thanks a lot! :) (I'll accept your answer later, it says I can only accept your answer in two minutes)

Comment: @Mordecaii I found it by looking up `excel 2010 function inside if` on Google, which returned this link: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx.  Your solution was found under Example 1.

Comment: @Mordecaii Still working?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, the = sign is used only at the beginning of a formula, unless there is a comparison with the *equal to* operator, which is also a = sign.